# Why can't I get onPageStarted, onReceivedError, or onPageFinished to ever call with Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I want to be able to recognize when an error occurs and tell show a toast message with the error but I can never get them to call. 
I also want to be able to tell when the webview starts navigating to a url and detect which url it's going to.

Unfortunately it just seems to ignore everything and I have no idea how to start a function or method or anything once this occurs.I don't really care how I go about determining when a page starts loading or an error occurs I just need a way that works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

       myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {

            private boolean error;


            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "page started:" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error = false;
            }


            public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)  {

                error = true;
                System.out.println("description error" + description);
                view.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (!error) {
                    view.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
                error = false;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "page finished" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );





        myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);


        // Other webview settings
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(this), "Android");

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");



    }

}
```

Comment: Override those methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onPageStarted()`, `onPageFinished()`, and `onReceivedError()` methods are not defined in the  [`WebChromeClient` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html). They're members of [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html). You subclassed the wrong one.

If you add the `@Override` annotation above each method, your IDE should yell at you that those methods don't override anything in the super class, which is why that annotation is useful.

Simply move those overrides to the `WebViewClient` instance.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        private boolean error;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ...
        }
    }
);

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: That makes sense. Are there alternative methods for WebChromeClient? I tried to look for some but the closest thing I can find is onProgressChanged and I really need to find errors somehow

Comment: Well, you could possibly use `onProgressChanged()` to the same effect as `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()`, but it's not really necessary. All you need to do is move that whole block of methods to the other object; i.e., move it to the end of `new WebViewClient()` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. For some reason I was thinking WebViewClient was an alternative to WebChromeClient not that they worked together.

Comment: Nope, they're separate things, and you can use them both simultaneously. I've never really figured out why they use two different classes, but _c'est la vie_. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is entire code with loader in Composable. In thissolution we need one more `if logic`, to not trigger methods `onPageFinished` unnecessarily

```
@Composable
fun WebViewContent(link: String) {
    var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var onPageStartedCalled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                WebView(context).apply {
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )

                    var wasCommitCalled = false

                    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                            view: WebView?,
                            url: String?
                        ): Boolean {
                            return if (view != null && url != null) {
                                checkShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
                            } else false
                        }

                        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                            wasCommitCalled = false
                            onPageStartedCalled = true
                            isLoading = true
                        }

                        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                            if (onPageStartedCalled) {
                                scope.launch {
                                    delay(1500)
                                    if (!wasCommitCalled) {
                                        if (url != null) {
                                            loadUrl(url)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    isLoading = false
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
                            wasCommitCalled = true
                        }
                    }

                    settings.setSupportZoom(true)
                    settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                    settings.displayZoomControls = false
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    settings.useWideViewPort = true

                    loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=$link")

                    this.setInitialScale(1)
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .then(Modifier.visibility(!isLoading))
        )

        LoaderContent(
            isLoading = isLoading
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Modifier.visibility(isVisible: Boolean): Modifier {
    return if (isVisible) this else alpha(0f)
}

fun checkShouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(
            ".docx"
        ) || url.endsWith(".ppt") || url.endsWith(".pptx")
    ) {
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$url")
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```